# Is it possible to restore config files overwritten by an upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, configuration

Not much to this story: When I upgraded to 20.04 LTS, it asked me whether to keep my version of several config files. I figured it would be safer to make sure I had the latest versions of everything, and I didn't think I had changed those config files.

Turns out I had, and some functionality I need is now missing. I'm not terribly experienced with Ubuntu, so if I have to redo the research and re-configure those functions, it's going to be a pain. I'm hoping those files might have gotten backed up somewhere during the upgrade, as reinstating them would obviously be a lot easier. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It normally saves them with a suffix of `.dpkg-old` and/or `.ucf-old`, e.g.

```
$ sudo find /etc -type f -name '*.dpkg*'
/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.dpkg-old
/etc/default/motd-news.dpkg-bak
/etc/ca-certificates.conf.dpkg-old
```

The correct answer however is, "restore from your backups".

Comment: One of the particular files I was looking for turned out to have the .ufc-old extension instead, but this got me close enough to resolve the issue. Thank you!